# Invalid xPath expression when using appium and winappdriver

Tags: xpath, automation, winappdriver, appium-desktop

I'm trying to select an email in my automation code in outlook. I want to select the email by the name but the name contains the send date that I don't know. So I'm trying to find it out after Xpath.

Here is how I try to find it.

```
'//@[starts-with(normalize-space(text()), "From user-1, Subject testing sendmail,")]'
```

I get this error:

```
Original error: Invalid XPath expression: //@[starts-with(normalize-space(text()), "From reporter-user-1, Sub
ject testing sendmail,")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//@` is invalid syntax. If you want to check `name` attribute you need to use either `//@*` or `//@name`